# How to add and use third party .dll in visual studio 2010, when no .lib is provided

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll

The manufacturer of a signal generator has given only a dll file.

How do I use it in my C++ program?
I will have to first add it in my project, but it requires a .lib file, which is not given. What do I do ?

I tired putting this dll along with the .exe, even then none of the functions of dll are working/recognized.

Comment: I believe you'll have to use the [`GetProcAddress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function

Comment: And [`LoadLibrary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx) to load the dll.

Comment: Check [this KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb%3Ben-us%3B131313&x=1&y=15) about two ways to generate the .lib file.

Comment: What do you have?  Header files?  Documentation showing exact data types and calling conventions?

Comment: Equipment vendors almost always supply COM servers.  Works in most any language.  Usable from C++ with the [#import directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8etzzkb6.aspx), basic COM Automation programming skills required.

Answer (score 2):

You have two alternatives:

1. Use [LoadLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx) and [GetProcAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212(v=vs.85).aspx), to get a handle to the DLL, then access the APIs you need by pointer into the DLL.
2. [Generate the lib](http://adrianhenke.wordpress.com/2008/12/05/create-lib-file-from-dll/) file yourself.

Comment: [This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) gives a nice, short example for the full process.

Comment: [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) may also be useful to take a look at the exported APIs & what other DLLs the DLL requires.